# URL to a particular section/page in a Word Document

Tags: html, ms-word

How do I give url links to particular sections of a word document through HTML hosted on a server root folder?

Answer (score 4):

It is possible to jump to a specific page when using Sharepoint or OneDrive. Your question is a little fuzzy (see below).

Here are the steps:

- First, get the URL to see the Word document (Right-click > Share)
- Append the following to the generated URL:

  `&action=embedview&wdStartOn=#`
- Replace # with the page number you want to jump to
- Test the new URL and share it.

The result should look more or less like this (anonymized, not working):

```
https://foo-my.sharepoint.com/:w:/r/personal/jastram_foo/_layouts/15/Doc.aspx?sourcedoc=%7Bc8ba7cf4-d124-4de9-9b58-4a5db4acd1a2%7D&action=embedview&wdStartOn=2
```

**Side note:** In your question it is unclear, whether you store the Word document just on a web server, whether you generated HTML from Word, or whether you are using Sharepoint/OneDrive.

Comment: hey @jastram, sorry to revive a necro, but I'm having an issue where I have a word doc on my Sharepoint, and I'm trying to link to a specific page, but for some reason it opens the file, but only to the cover sheet, not the right page. any ideas? I suspect microsoft pushing their web viewer has something to do with it

Comment: @acousticismX There are no necros on Stack Overflow.  Enduring post value is our goal.

Comment: When adding `&action=embedview&wdStartOn=#` be sure to look for existing query string parameter `&action=default` or similiar and remove it. This may be your issue @acousticismX

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

How to create a hyperlink from an HTML page to a bookmark in Word
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310520

Comment: Sorry to bother you so much time later, but do you happen to know if the technique listed in the kb article should still be valid? Have tried with office 2007/2010 but the "Http://document_url#bookmark_name" syntax doesn't seem to work.

Comment: The link is not working any more, I provided an alternative answer.

Comment: @jastram where is your alternative answer?

Comment: @Mark - It's the answer above: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49811596/314618

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to link to specific sections of Word Documents saved on SharePoint. I have done it in the past on an SOP document using the information in the below link. Hope it is helpful in your case too.

https://www.success-trending.club/2020/03/linking-to-bookmark-in-word-document.html